# Which is correct: "Filename", "File Name" or "FileName"?

Tags: orthography, capitalization, programming, spacing, camel-case

Which is correct: "Filename", "File Name" or "FileName"?

Comment: Or "File-name"?

Comment: I like the look of `filename`, however, when you end up talking about other _attributes_ of that _file_, which happens in programming a lot, for example, it is often much better to use `file name` instead. This way you can do `file name`, `file size`, `file format`, etc. without losing the symmetry, as you would with `filename`, `file size`, `file format`, etc.

Comment: Of note, the `Content-Disposition` header in web requests accepts a value of `filename="file.txt"`, indicating that they have standardized on the use of `filename` as opposed to `file_name`.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The original form of the word was "file name", as in the name of a file. These days (and probably for a good few years), the compound "filename" is widely accepted and perhaps most commonly used. Either is of course perfectly acceptable.

Do not, however, capitalise letters in the middle of a word, under any circumstances. (Unless you are writing variable names in code.)

Comment: Similarly, don't use "File Name". There is no reason "Name" should ever be capitalized in the middle of a sentence. (Unless, I suppose, someone is named "Name", but that takes pedantry to new extremes.)

Comment: @res: Yeah, that's a given. :) You don't want to capitalise either of the words unless "File" begins a sentence.

Comment: I have never known "filename" to be a widely used closed-form compound term; there are, indeed, many instances of it around (particularly in code), but that doesn't _necessarily_ make it correct. A generic term could be used which makes the use of either word redundant, and that is "path" - this applies to both files and directories, since both are simply file system objects.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that Microsoft themselves don't consider "filename" appropriate in their [Design Guidelines for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx) - so, they're not an authority on English language, but they do set standards in a vast amount of computing arenas (particularly worth heeding if this is programming related.)

Comment: I agree with Microsoft here, yeah. Funnily enough I've noticed they don't *always* follow this rule in their APIs, but mostly, they do.

Comment: "Under any circumstances" is a bit extreme. Consider for instance proper nouns such as MacDonald, McAfee, iPad, and iiNet.

Comment: @aamos: I mean in words that would normally not have their letters capitalised; non-proper nouns, of course.

Comment: @Noldorin Since OP tagged it programming and programmers like me will be flowing in here, it might be good to promote the design guidelines link to the answer.

Comment: @jnm2: Nope, the OP didn't tag it as such, another user did that shortly after (indeed after my answer). Anyway, I think the answer is already complete enough.

Comment: @GrantThomas - the programming term "path" generally refers to a filename plus the directory structure necessary to get to it (e.g. `/path/to/file.txt`, `../file.txt`). "filename" is generally used for just the last part (e.g. If path == '/path/to/file.txt', then filename == 'file.txt'). If you're in the same directory as the file, the "filename" and "path" are effectively the same. But from any other place, they are necessarily different.

Comment: @AlanW.Smith Not necessarily... the "path" just means it's a full specification (absolute or relative) of how to find a file *or* directory, as the name would suggest, rather than just a file or directory name.

Comment: @res Note "File Name" could be alright in a headline, see ["Title Case"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Title_case) (e.g. "Area Man Mistypes File Name and Deletes Bitcoin Savings")

Comment: Noldorin: Your last comment = @AlanW.Smith's last comment = "<Path> = [<Directory>]<File Name>".  Alan never said "path" = "file or directory name".  He said "path" = "filename *plus* the directory" but also said the "directory" part is optional "If you're in the same directory as the file, the "filename"".

Comment: Just to emphasise the naming here - **FileName** would be Pascal case, mainly used for the naming of methods or properties, whereas **fileName** is camel case and would be used as variable definitions within the code. As pointed out by others in this thread, however, it's a poor naming convention unless it refers to something very generic, such as many unrelated files.

Answer (score 30):

*Filename* is in my experience the most common and in my opinion the best looking. *File name* is also acceptable, but I would only use it rarely, perhaps in a parallel construction such as *the file name and size*. I find word-medial capital letters distracting and unpleasant anywhere but program source code, so I would never even think of *FileName*. **Edit:** if that's the reason you're asking, in program source I would still use `Filename` for a class or `filename` for a variable, not `FileName` nor `fileName`, respectively.

The British National Corpus has 240 cites for *filename* and 72 cites for *file name*. It's not possible to search case-sensitively, but several reloads of the random sample of specific entries gave me no matches for *FileName*.

Comment: In the parallel construction example, wouldn't you more correctly say _the file's name and size_?

Comment: @LucasTizma: Appositive and possessive both work.

Comment: Hm, I always use `file_name`

Comment: @JonPurdy thanks for the variable name clarification

Comment: This works great until you also need to refer to a different attribute of the `file`, say the "size". Then do you do `filesize` or do you do `file size`? I would personally prefer keeping the object and the attribute separate so that you can expand on it if necessary: `file name`, `file size`, `file type`, etc.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter in the BNC used above, file size is cited, but filesize is not. As a native speaker, intuitively I would only use filename as a solid compound noun. Other nouns with the head of "file" I would separate by a space.

Comment: @Blaisem Exactly. So, as a software engineering, I would prefer to also use `file name` instead of `filename`. This way, it is consistent with `file size`, `file type`, `file path`, etc.

Answer (score 8):

The *AHD* has an entry for “filename”, so it is, at least, an established American English word. Thus it is “correct” for some situations.

Update: the word “pathname” is also included in the *American Heritage Dictionary: Fifth Edition*. So over time I will be changing my program variables from SettingFilePathName to SettingFilePathname.

Answer (score 3):

None of them. "filename" is not a proper noun, and thus should not be capitalized. If you begin a sentence with the word, then it should be "Filename".

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I would say "filename", as that is what I have seen used in most software development textbooks. That's not to say that this is the standard by which all words should be measured, but given that the word is generally used in relation to computers I would imagine that it is safe to use.

Answer (score 1):

Any two words (such as 'file name') used together for long enough periods of time end up with a single meaning in our collective language. When that happens, you can combine the two, though it's not advisable for formal usage.
Words such as, for example, 'himself' are older, and common examples from the computer age include 'username', 'email', and 'desktop'.

For formal usage, consider spacing the words or using a hyphen, where appropriate.

Comment: I somehow do not like “file-name” even in formal context.  Both “filename” and “file name” are fine.

Comment: To clarify: some word combinations use spaces, while others use hyphens. By "where appropriate," I meant that you should use whichever you find appropriate.

Comment: ‘Email’ should be a completely unacceptable spelling. The ‘e’ is an abbreviation of electronic, thus, the spelling should be e-mail. Allowing the hyphen to magically disappear makes it very inconsistent. What happens, then, to words like e-economy? How about h-bomb, t-bone, and x-ray?

Comment: @FrederikKrautwald late to the party, but [it's an internet thing](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/email.html), and totally different from how we got h-bomb/t-bone/x-ray, so those would probably never undergo that process. I've never once seen 'e-economy' but I suspect 'digital economy' is better anyway.

Comment: I am only here to comment on @Federik Krautwald's comment to say that "email" has been the correct spelling for a long time now. If you use "e-mail" you will really be dating yourself to say the least, and you might as well call the internet the "information super highway." https://www.grammarly.com/blog/spelling-e-mail-email/#:~:text=E%2Dmail%20and%20email%20are,to%20spell%20the%20same%20word.&text=Even%20though%20it%20seems%20that,older%20version%2C%20e%2Dmail.

Answer (score 0):

The OED has no entry for "filename." However, being a technical writer of 25 years, I have adopted this spelling because programmers and engineers prefer it. Still, it seems odd to me.

Comment: I looked up today and found http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/filename.